# Kernel of the linear operator from $P_{5}$ to $R^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider $T$ , the  linear  operator from  $P_{5}$  , the  vector  space  of  polynomials  of  degree  at most $5$   to  $R^{2}$  given  by  $T(p(x))=(p(3),p'(3))$  where   $p'$  is  the  derivative  of  $p$ . What  is  the  kernel  of  $T$ ? What  is  the  basis  of  the  kernel ?

Now considering $\{x^{i}\}_{i=0}^{5}$ as  the  basis  none  of  them  goes  to  $(0,0)$  identically .So  I  guess  this  is  not  the  basis  that  consists  of  the  basis  of  the  kernel .

From  the  basic  definition  of  the  kernel taking  $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{5} a_{i}x^{i}$  with $p(3)=0$  and  $p'(3)=0$  we get two  equations  in  $6$  variables  so  may be  choosing  $4$  of  them  arbitrarily the  other  $2$  can  be  obtained  so  may  be  the  dimension  is  $4$ . But  then  what  is  the  basis  of  the  kernel?

On  the  other  hand any  polynomial $p$  such  that  both  $p$  and  $p'$  are  $0$  at  $3$  must  have $(x-3)^{2}$  as  a  factor  i.e  $\ $ $x^{2}-6x+9$ $\ $ as  a  factor. Can  I  guess  the  basis  of  the  kernel  from  here?

Comment: Small linguistic point: When you speak of "_the_ basis", you're implicitly asserting that a basis is unique, which (except as noted below) is never the case. Instead, speak of "_a_ basis". :) (Tangential exercise: Characterize the vector spaces having a unique basis. Up to isomorphism, precisely one has positive dimension.)

Answer (score 1):

You know that $\text{ker}T$ is 4-dimensional (beacuse image of $T$ is 2-dimensional). But polynomials $P_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are linear independent if they have different degrees, so:

$$p_1(x)=(x-3)^2$$
$$p_2(x)=(x-3)^3$$
$$p_3(x)=(x-3)^4$$
$$p_4(x)=(x-3)^5$$

Are linear independent. $\text{ker}T$ is 4-dimensional, so they form a basis.

Comment: Just  one question .Take any  element  from  $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ say $(\alpha , \beta )$  then  we  will  find  a  polynomial  $p$  such  that  $p(3)=\alpha$  and  $p'(3)=\beta$ . since  the  range  is  $2$-dimensional so  consists  of  the  whole  space  $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ .So  we   have  to  solve $2$  the  equations  $p(3)=\alpha$  and  $p'(3)=\beta$  of  $6$   variables. So  we  shall  get  more  than  $1$  polynomials  satisfying  the  conditions. No  problem  that  since it  is  not  an  injective  map as  the  kernel  is  not  $0$.  Is  my  reasoning  right?

Comment: @user118494, yes, it is right.

Answer (score 0):

Given $p(x)$= $ax^5+ bx^4+ cx^3+ dx^2+ ex+ f$, $p'(x)$= $5ax^4+ 4bx^3+ 3cx^2+ 2dx+ e$.
$T(p)= (243a+ 81b+ 27c+ 9d+ 3e+ f, 405a+ 108b+ 27c+ 6d+ e)$.  In order that $p$ be in the kernel of $T$, we must have $243a+ 81b+ 27c+ 9d+ 3e+ f= 0$, $405a+ 108b+ 27c+ 6d+ e= 0$.  We can use those two equations to solve for two of the coefficients, say, $e$ and $f$ since they are easiest, in terms of the other $4$.   From $405a+ 108b+ 27c+ 6d+ e= 0, e= -405a- 108b- 27c- 6d= 0$.  Then the first equation, $243a+ 81b+ 27c+ 9d+ 3e+ f= 0,$ becomes $243a+ 81b+ 27c+ 9d- 1215a- 324b- 81c- 18d- 9d+ f= -972a- 242b- 54c- 27d+ f= 0$ so $f= 972a+ 242b+ 54c+ 27d.$

Any $p(x)$ in the kernel is of the form $p(x)= ax^5+ bx^4+ cx^3+ dx^2+ (-405a- 108b- 27c- 6d)x+ (972a+ 242b+ 54c+ 27d)= a(x^5- 405x+ 972)+ b(x^4- 108x+ 242)+ c(x^3- 27x+ 54)+d(x^2- 6x+ 27)$.

A basis for that kernel is $\{x^5- 405x+ 972, x^4- 108x+ 242, x^3- 27x+ 54, x^2- 6x+ 27\}.$